# I'm creating a list of every ip address and checking it for 443, but it wont append to file. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, bash

When I enter

```py
import os   
for i in range(255):  
    for n in range (255):  
        for k in range (255):  
            f = "nmap -sL -n "+str(i)+"."+str(n)+"."+str(k)+".0/27 | wsl awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}' >> list.txt"  
            os.system(f)
```

I get a file that reaches 1 kb then overwrites instead of appending like the >> function should.

Comment: How do you know that it overwrites?

Comment: repeatedly gets to 1 kb then 0 kb in a loop

Comment: How do you determine the file size while the program is running?